# How to fix ng-if not reacting?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, conditional-statements

I'm trying to display a link `<a href>` when a condition is met, but the link never appears.

I have already tried to change the position (in/out of `<div controller>`) and the tag of the item containing the `ng-if` (`span`, `div`, `ul`...). This kind of code works on another HTML I have, so my Angular version seems okay.

Here is the form where I call the controller:

```html
<div ng-controller="userRole">
      <form ng-submit="setProfile()">
        <select ng-model="userRole"
                ng-options="role for role in roles">Role</select>
        <input type="text"
                ng-model="userName"
                placeholder="Nom"></input>
        <input type="submit"
               value="Valider"></input>
      </form>
    </div>
```

The condition right after:

```html
<span ng-if="user.isSetup">
      <a href="srsApp.html">Accès aux cours</a>
    </span>
```

And the actual controller:

```
      var app = angular.module('srsApp', []);
      app.controller('userRole', function($scope) {
        $scope.roles = ['Professeur', 'Élève'];
        $scope.user = {role:'', name:'', isSetup: false};

        $scope.setProfile = function() {
          if ($scope.userName !== '' && $scope.userRole !== '') {
            $scope.user.role = $scope.userRole;
            $scope.user.role = $scope.userName;
            $scope.user.isSetup = true;
            $scope.userRole = '';
            $scope.userName = '';
          }
        };
      });
    </script>
```

I expected the link to appear once I submit the form with a role and a name, but the link stays hidden. No error from my Firefox terminal, and I know it enters the function because the placeholders are re-initialized.

Comment: The `<span>` with `ng-if` is outside `<div ng-controller="userRole">`?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava true. It works now. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As mentionned by @AnuragSrivastava, the `<span>` should be in the `<div ng-controller="userRole">`. As I said I tried it, but previous circumstances (syntax errors NOT highlighted by terminal) prevented this to work.